# As a half-orc barbarian, how can you increase your chance of getting a critical hit?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, barbarian, critical-hit, half-orc

I noticed that barbarians have a [Brutal Critical](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#BrutalCritical-64) feature, and half-orcs also have a similar trait ([Savage Attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/2-half-orc#Half-OrcTraits)).

As a half-orc barbarian, how can you increase your crit chance?

I'm looking for anything before I attempt this character. Min/max'ing appreciated. This is for D&D 5e.

Comment: Most of the ways to get better crits involve multiclassing that's going to delay or lock out your Brutal Critical increases, so I'm not sure a crit-fishing barbarian even makes sense.

Comment: Welcome to the stack Ethan, take the [tour] when you have a moment. I’ve closed this as a duplicate of our Q&A that documents all the ways to increase critical hit chance. Don’t worry, duplicates are okay, they can help others find the answers they’re looking for by expanding the pool of search results.